Issue : Converting CRACO SASS Loader Settings to Webpack Configuration
I wants to modify some SASS loader configurations to support some upgraded version of libraries.
I have a working code configuration of craco, the same I wanted to achieve with webpack.
CRACO configuration (working with "craco start")=
module.exports ={
    style: {
      sass: {
        loaderOptions: (sassLoaderOptions) => {
          sassLoaderOptions.sassOptions = {
            ...sassLoaderOptions.sassOptions,
            includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules/')]
          };
          return sassLoaderOptions;
        }
      }
    }
  }

WEBPACK configuration (Not Working with 'react-scripts start')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Loads CSS into the DOM via a <style> tag
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

Giving Error -

ERROR in ./src/index.scss
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet1.rules1.oneOf[7].use1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet1.rules1.oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet1.rules1.oneOf[7].use[3]!./no2
│ @use 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';   │
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ╵
node_modules@ey-xd\motif-react\components\forms\date-picker_date-picker.scss
2:1  @forward
node_modules@ey-xd\motif-react\components_components.scss 17:1
@forward   node_modules@ey-xd\motif-react\styles.scss 2:1
@forward   src\index.scss 4:1
root stylesheet
webpack compiled with 1 error and 7 warnings Files successfully
emitted, waiting for typecheck results... Issues checking in
progress... No issues found.


